# Lithium Epub Reader app crashed and data seems to have deleted itself - any way to recover?

Tags: data-recovery, ebook-reader

I've been using the Lithium Epub Reader app for about a year on my Android phone and had built up a lot of highlights, categories notes, etc. Today, the app crashed, restarted, and started re-syncing with the epub files on my phone as if it was installed for the first time. Highlights, notes, reading progress, etc., all seem lost.

Is there anything I can do to recover the data?